# Combine Python Pandas Dataframe more Efficiently than List Append Method

Tags: python, json, pandas

I keep having to do the below to build up dataframes from a small pipeline processing individual json lines. Is there a more efficient way to do this instead of relying on appending them to a list and then concatenating? Also I don't even need the column labels below represented as "key" but wasn't sure how to exclude them without getting dataframe constructor errors:

```
def readfiles(pattern, textfile):
    for line in open(textfile):
        try:
            parsed = ujson.loads(line.rstrip('\n').rstrip(','))
            if pattern in parsed:
                yield parsed
        except ValueError, e:
            pass

def convertodf(lines):
    dfs = []
    for line in lines:
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'key1':line['value'],
                                       'key2':line['value']['value'],
                                       'key3':line['value'],
                                       'key4':line['value']['value'],
                                       'key5':line['value']['value']}))

    pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).to_csv('testdf2.csv', index=False, header=None)

def main(pattern, filenames):
    lines = readfiles(pattern, filenames)
    convertodf(lines)
```

The really cool part with the above implementation is that one of the line['value'] elements is actually a comma separated list of integers such as [1,2,3] and it ends up automatically duplicating the other values accordingly such as:

```
'key1' 'key2'
  1     california
  2     california
  3     california
        ...
```

Here is my final working version I went with thanks to unutbu's help.

```
def readfiles(pattern, filedir):
        for f in glob.glob(filedir+'*.zip'):
            try:
                with zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r') as myzip:
                    for logfile in myzip.namelist():
                        for line in myzip.open(logfile):
                            try:
                                line = ujson.loads(line.rstrip('\n').rstrip(','))
                                if pattern in line:
                                    for i in line['key1']:
                                        yield i, line['key1']['key2'],\
                                    line['key3'], line['key4']['key5'],\
                                    line['key6']['key7']
                            except ValueError as err:
                                pass
            except zipfile.error, e:
                pass

def convertdfcsv(lines):
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines)
        df.to_csv('testdf2.csv', index=False, header=None)

def main(pattern):
        lines = readfiles(pattern)
        convertdf(lines)
```

Comment: Is it possible to load the entire contents of `textfile` with one call to `ujson.load`?

Comment: Each textfile contains around 50K lines with each line represented as a json object so I don't think so. That's why I have to unfortunately loop through the lines in textfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the DataFrame from a row-iterator using [DataFrame.from_records](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas-dataframe-from-records).
A simple example which shows how `from_records` works is:

```
iterator = (item for item in [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5]])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(iterator,
                               columns=list('abcd'))
print(df)
#    a  b  c   d
# 0  1  2  3 NaN
# 1  2  3  4   5
```

---

Applied to your situation, the code could look something like:

```
def readfiles(pattern, filenames):
    for textfile in filenames:
        with open(textfile, 'rb') as f:
            for line in f:
                try:
                    line = ujson.loads(line.rstrip('\n').rstrip(','))
                    if pattern in line:
                        yield line['value'], line['value']['value'], line['value'], line['value']['value'], line['value']['value']
                except ValueError as err:
                    pass

def convertodf(lines):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines)
    df.to_csv('testdf2.csv', index=False, header=None)

def main(pattern, filenames):
    lines = readfiles(pattern, filenames)
    convertodf(lines)
```

Comment: This is really great. The only quirky part I should have mentioned was that in the dict dataframe construction implementation I posted one of the key:value pairs is a list of integers that was acting sort of like an index causing all of the other values to be duplicated and connected to each element in the list. For example, is there a way to have one of the line['value'] from the yield behave the same way?

Comment: In that case, use a `for-loop` to iterate over the list and yield each of rows.